# mongoose find query to perform multiple condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables vendor and vendorOrg table. I needs to return the list based on vendorOrg table criteria wise and category -wise

```
const vendors = [{
  "name" : "Alfred",
  "location" : "FH",
  "vendorOrgId" : "1"
},
{
  "name" : "Alfred",
  "location" : "ADH",
  "vendorOrgId" : "2"
},
{
  "name" : "Alfred",
  "location" : "AFF",
  "vendorOrgId" : "41"
}]

const vendorOrg = [
  {
    "orgName" : "star super market",
    "vendorOrgId" : "1",
    "category" : "grocery",
    "status" : "active"
  },
  {
    "orgName" : "L.f super market",
    "vendorOrgId" : "41",
    "category" : "grocery",
    "status" : "active"
  },
  {
    "orgName" : "Fresh mart",
    "vendorOrgId" : "2",
    "category" : "Milk",
    "status" : "active"
  }
]
```

find conditions below,
1.vendor's table vendorOrgId must be same as vendorOrg's table id.
2. vendorOrg table status should active.
if above conditions are true, the i needs a vendor list category-wise, based on vendorOrg's table category.

```
{
    "grocery": [{
            "name": "Alfred",
            "location": "FH",
            "vendorOrgId": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alfred",
            "location": "AFF",
            "vendorOrgId": "41"
        }
    ],
    "milk": [{
        "name": "Alfred",
        "location": "ADH",
        "vendorOrgId": "2"
    }]
}
```

Is this possible to do with mongoose.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- `$lookup` with vendorLog collection and pass `vendorOrgId` to lookup pipeline
- `$match` required conditions
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct `org` array
- `$group` by `org category` and construct array of `vendors`
- `$group` by null and construct array in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value pair array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object to root

```
db.vendors.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vendorOrg",
      let: { vendorOrgId: "$vendorOrgId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$vendorOrgId", "$vendorOrgId"] },
            status: "active"
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 1, category: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "org"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$org" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$org.category",
      vendors: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          location: "$location",
          vendorOrgId: "$vendorOrgId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      vendors: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$vendors" } }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$vendors" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ju8WXrYlu4)